# How to I run extent report in parallel suit in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

I have created a Parallel suit and added parameters such as firefox, chrome etc. My issue is that when i run the suit, it logs results for the very first run. For example, if i am doing cross browser, so my test will run in firefox, and chrome so firefox triggers first. The issue is that the result logs are displayed only for fire fox driver. Below is my code. Please someone advice.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Cross Browser Testing" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
<test name="Firefox Test">
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="mwgToQuotients.ResponsiveHeaderFooter1"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Chrome Test">
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name="mwgToQuotients.ResponsiveHeaderFooter1"></class>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>


@BeforeClass
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    public void setUp(String browser) {
        report = new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\aaarb00\\Desktop\\Quotients\\MWG Reports\\QuotientCrossBrowser.html");
        test = report.startTest("Functional Test");
        baseURL = "http://ngcp-qi.safeway.com/";

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\aaarb00\\Desktop\\Quotients\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            hp = new HomePage(driver, test);
            lp = new SignInPage(driver, test);
            sl = new StoreLocatorPage(driver);
            wa = new WeeklyAdPage(driver, test);
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "C:\\Users\\aaarb00\\Desktop\\Quotients\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            hp = new HomePage(driver, test);
            lp = new SignInPage(driver, test);
            sl = new StoreLocatorPage(driver);
            wa = new WeeklyAdPage(driver, test);
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseURL);
```

Comment: Where are you logging your results?

Comment: @ Manoj Kengudelu in an xml file